# Boosting multiple "terms" in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, boosting

Instead of multiple fields to match, I want to give a boosted score. It's part of a bigger query, so unfortunately I cannot avoid having to boost this part of the query.

I tried:

```
   "terms": {
            "some.keyword": ["a12c", "b12c"],
            "boost": 10
   }
```

and:

```
   "terms": {
       "some.keyword": {
           "values": ["a12c", "b12c"], 
           "boost": 10
       } 
   }
```

but both do not work.

Comment: `boost` for `terms` should work. If it seems it doesn't, then your other parts of the "bigger query" do something to the score.

Comment: @AndreiStefan In the documentation it doesn't state it has an effect. Also, I specifically tested it by seeing no difference in "max_score" given any boost value.

Comment: Is this question really about [Boost C++ Libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/boost/info) as the tag would suggest? Please, next time take the moment to read the tag description before you use the tag (it even shows up as you type the tags). (Fixed)